# Momentjs is showing 1day further than expected

Tags: momentjs

I m using momentjs for one of my projects,I have set the default time zone to this:

```
moment.tz.setDefault("Asia/Kolkata");
```

and here is the route where im trying to find the difference between dates

```
app.get("/test/new",function(req,res){
var output1=moment("20200401", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();
res.render("new",{output:output,output1:output1});
```

})

The output must be 1day ago but im receiving output as 2days ago.Can someone help me out
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 22 to 35 hours   =   a day ago
- 36 hours to 25 days  =   2 days ago ... 25 days ago

And check it out : https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/

Comment: it was just 23 hours past it must show a day ago not 2 days ago

Comment: it was just 23 hours past not 24 hours

Comment: 23 hours and what about minutes upto 23 hours